Separating Music Files by USB Port on Android Tablet
I'm working on an Android project that involves playing music on a tablet. This tablet has multiple USB ports, and my goal is to read and display the music from each connected USB device separately, organized by tabs.
I tried using ContentResolver to collect the music files, but I encountered an issue: it brought all the music files mixed together, regardless of which USB port they came from. I would like an approach that allows me to list the music files separately for each connected USB device.
Can anyone help with tips or guidance on how to achieve this separation? Is there a better way to access and organize these files?
Thank you in advance for your help!
